# Problem with upload multiple file in list box c# windows form

Tags: c#, windows, forms, pdf

I'm writing software in C# and Windows Form.
This software must be able to read a PDF and extract information from it.
The problem arises when I want to upload a huge amount of PDFs, like 200/300 PDFs.
I take the PDFs with an open file dialog with multiple selection support and load the path into a list combo box.
In the development phase a dozen load them, while if I release the software as .exe it loads only one at a time.
Can you help me understand what is wrong with my approach/code?

```
  private void listBoxPdf_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] s = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop,false);
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<s.Length;i++)
        {
            listBoxPdf.Items.Add(s[i]);
        }
    }

    private void listBoxPdf_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void listBoxPdf_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.C)
        {
            try
            {
                if (listBoxPdf.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    listBoxPdf.Items.RemoveAt(listBoxPdf.SelectedIndex);
                    listBoxPdf.EndUpdate();
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Non ci sono elementi da cancellare!");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "sono nel catch di quando premi C per cancellare un elemento dalla lista");
            }
        }
     }private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (listBoxPdf.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Non ci sono elementi da salvare!");
        }
        else
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            this.pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            this.pictureBox1.Image = 
            WindowsFormsApp.Properties.Resources.Salvataggio_in_Corso____;
            this.bunifuProgressBarSaveDate.Visible = true;
            this.labelProgressBar.Visible = true;
        });
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        });

            for (int a = 0; a < listBoxPdf.Items.Count; a++)
            {
                try
                {
                    file = listBoxPdf.Items[a].ToString();
                    if (file != null)
                    {
                    string extn = new FileInfo(file).Extension;
                        SingletonIstance.getInstance.DatiScambio._FileEXTN = extn;
                        List<string> documentList = new List<string>();
                        using (var pdf = PdfDocument.Open(file))
                        {
                            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                            StringBuilder builder_ = new StringBuilder();
                            for (var j = 0; j < pdf.NumberOfPages; j++)
                            {
                            algorithm that extract data from pdf
                            }
                       }
                    }
                 }
               catch(Exception ex){

                   }
            }
```

}